# Python Crash Course 9-8, Attribute issue

Tags: python

```
class User():

  def __init__(self,first,last,sex,age):
    self.first_name=first
    self.last_name=last
    self.sex = sex
    self.age =age
    self.login_attempts = 0

  def describe_users(self):
    print(self.first_name + " " +self.last_name)
    print("Gender: " + self.sex)
    print("Age: " + str(self.age))

  def greeting_users(self):
    print("Welcome, " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + "!\n")

  def increment_login_attempts(self):
    self.login_attempts += 1
    print("Login attempts: " + str(self.login_attempts))

  def reset_login_attempts(self):
    self.login_attempts = 0
    print("Login has been reset")

class Privileges():

  def __init__(self,privileges):
    self.privileges= ['can add post','can delete post', 'can ban user']

  def show_privileges(self):
    for x in self.privileges:
      print("The Admin can " + x)

class Admin(User):

  def __init__(self,first,last,sex,age):
    """Initialize attributes of the parent class"""
    super().__init__(first,last,sex,age)
    self.privileges = Privileges()

person_admin= Admin('Kevin','Mark','M',30)
person_admin.Privileges.show_privileges()
```

So I am having trouble solving this problem. I keep on getting the error Typeerror. Wondering if any of you guys know where the problem is at? The goal of this problem is to make a "Privileges" instance as an attribute in the "Admin" class. After, create a new instance of "Admin" and use "show_privileges" to show its privileges.

Comment: You should really post the exact error that you are seeing--it makes it far easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The exact error is probably this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 42, in <module>
  File "python", line 40, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges'
```

It's because you've written the constructor for Privileges to require an argument, but you haven't passed that argument when instantiating Privileges in the constructor for Admin. Just change the constructor for Privileges to this:

```
def __init__(self):  # removed argument "privileges"
    self.privileges = ['can add post','can delete post', 'can ban user']
```

Then on the last line you'll want to lower-case *Privileges*, because you're referring to the instance rather than the class.

```
person_admin.privileges.show_privileges()
```

You can check out the [working code here](https://repl.it/LfmV).